# View the original post when editing

Tags: feature-request

While doing some heavy editing I sometime need to recheck the original post to be sure to not change the meaning of it. Right now I do this by coping the original in notepad, or by reopening the question in another tab.

Having an interface similar to the one in the Suggested Edit review, with the two version placed side by side, will be really useful.

Comment: Nah. It just takes up more screen space. Not a problem when I'm on my desktop, but it is, when I'm tweaking posts on my tablet.

Comment: Then maybe tabbed, more than tweaking I think of when you need to nearly rewrite someone else post to make it make sense

Comment: So, instead of just opening the question in a new tab, you want SO to implement exactly that, on the page?

Comment: I've been meaning to post something like this myself. I think it would be helpful to be able to see a diff of baseline vs. current edit while editing, especially when improving a suggested edit.

Comment: Rewrite/copy and paste what you're planning on editing to the line above/below. When you're done, just delete the original line. Why do we need two versions side by side?

Comment: What if the OP made edits to the original post? It shouldn't matter if they made the changes.